# Unable to drop privileges for a new process with QProcess in PyQt4

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

This question is about PyQt4, but I'm not concerned about portability. The target system is GNU/Linux only.

I have a small program which should be run using **kdesudo**/**kdesu**/**gtksu** or similar.
At some point I need to start a new process pretending to be the original user who ran the command.
In the doc ([here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#setupChildProcess) and [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qprocess.html#setupChildProcess)) I read that I should override the `setupChildProcess` method. So this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from os import setgroups, setuid, setgid, environ
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        testme = QtGui.QPushButton('\nTEST ME\n')
        self.connect(testme, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.test)
        self.setCentralWidget(testme)

    def test(self):
        sp = SandboxProcess()
        sp.startDetached('id')

class SandboxProcess(QtCore.QProcess):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SandboxProcess, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        env = environ.copy()
        if 'SUDO_USER' in environ:
            username = environ['SUDO_USER']
            del env['SUDO_USER']
            del env['SUDO_GID']
            del env['SUDO_UID']
        elif 'KDESU_USER' in environ:
            username = environ['KDESU_USER']
            del env['KDESU_USER']
        else:
            username = 'nobody'
        env['USERNAME'] = username
        env['LOGNAME'] = username
        env['USER'] = username
        env['MAIL'] = '/var/mail/' + username
        env['HOME'] = '/home/' + username
        qenv = QtCore.QProcessEnvironment()
        for k, v in env.iteritems():
            qenv.insert(k, v)
        self.setProcessEnvironment(qenv)

    def setupChildProcess(self):
        super(SandboxProcess, self).setupChildProcess()
        if 'SUDO_USER' in environ:
            gid = environ['SUDO_GID']
            uid = environ['SUDO_UID']
        elif 'KDESU_USER' in environ:
            gid = environ['KDE_SESSION_UID']
            uid = environ['KDE_SESSION_UID']
        else:
            uid = 65534
            gid = 65534
        setgroups([])
        setgid(int(gid))
        setuid(int(uid))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

First of all, I know that I'm not cleaning the environment in the best way possible, but this is just a proof of concept to show you my problem.

My problem is that the command is still executed as root. Also it seems that the `setupChildProcess` is not called at all.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried calling sp.setupChildProcess() directly?

Comment: Yes, but this way it will change the uid also for the *parent* process. Also in the doc it says that *setupChildProcess* is called automatically. Anyway thank you for your comment.

Comment: I suggest that setProcessEnvironment() should be called before the process is run; why setupChildProcess() isn't being automatically executed I don't know, but I'm pretty sure the environment referred to by setProcessEnvironment() should be set first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer on my own. I'll post it here for future reference.

The problem described in this question does only exist when you use `startDetached` instead of `start`.
The reason is that `startDetached` is implemented as a **static method** of the parent class, so it will never see my override of `setupChildProcess`.
To avoid this situation you *should* first start the process using `start` and then you *should* detach it. Unfortunately, as you can see [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-9328), this is not possible at the moment.

My workaround is to use another script as a "proxy" for detaching the process:

*detach.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from sys import argv
from os import devnull
from subprocess import Popen

with open(devnull, "w") as fnull:
    Popen(argv[1:], stdout = fnull, stderr = fnull, close_fds=True)
```

example.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from os import setgroups, setuid, setgid, environ
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        testme = QtGui.QPushButton('\nTEST ME\n')
        self.connect(testme, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.test)
        self.setCentralWidget(testme)

    def test(self):
        sp = SandboxProcess()
        sp.start('python2 ./detach.py firefox')
        sp.waitForFinished()
        print str(sp.readAllStandardOutput()).strip()

class SandboxProcess(QtCore.QProcess):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SandboxProcess, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        env = environ.copy()
        if 'SUDO_USER' in environ:
            username = environ['SUDO_USER']
            del env['SUDO_USER']
            del env['SUDO_GID']
            del env['SUDO_UID']
        elif 'KDESU_USER' in environ:
            username = environ['KDESU_USER']
            del env['KDESU_USER']
        else:
            username = 'nobody'
        env['USERNAME'] = username
        env['LOGNAME'] = username
        env['USER'] = username
        env['MAIL'] = '/var/mail/' + username
        env['HOME'] = '/home/' + username
        #cleaning environment....
        qenv = QtCore.QProcessEnvironment()
        for k, v in env.iteritems():
            qenv.insert(k, v)
        self.setProcessEnvironment(qenv)

    def setupChildProcess(self):
        super(SandboxProcess, self).setupChildProcess()
        if 'SUDO_USER' in environ:
            gid = environ['SUDO_GID']
            uid = environ['SUDO_UID']
        elif 'KDESU_USER' in environ:
            gid = environ['KDE_SESSION_UID']
            uid = environ['KDE_SESSION_UID']
        else:
            uid = 65534
            gid = 65534
        setgroups([])
        setgid(int(gid))
        setuid(int(uid))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    exit(app.exec_())
```

I've also moved the environment-related code in the `__init__` instead of `setupChildProcess` following the suggestion of @mdurant.